# How to get the content outside of an element

Tags: jquery, parent

Below is my code, my goal is when the user clicks the button with a class named `click_me`, I want to alert the content inside the class named `content`. I've tried doing:

**JS:**

```
alert($(this).closest('.content').html());
```

*But it didn't work.*

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
    <div class="content">Hello</div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="button" class="click_me" value="Click Me"/></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.content').html());
```

Comment: Another question, how do you hide the outer parent which is the <tr>?

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').hide();`

Comment: It is hiding the outermost <tr> and not the closest

Comment: This should work. Something is wrong somewhere else! I can see you are missing `td`s inside the `tr`s...

Comment: Dude, if I can mark this answer correct twice I would. It works! Thanks for noticing that

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 $(".click_me").on("click",function(){
   alert($(".content").html());
 });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.content').html());
```